# Communication with server not working when app is downloaded from the store

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, server, retrofit

I'm using retrofit for the communication between the app and the server. When I'm testing it with android studio everything works fine and the comunication is successful. However, when the app is downloaded from the store, when I try to post something to the server nothing happens, and I don't get an error. Does anyone know why this is happening?

UPDATE:
Here is my build.gradle. Maybe there is something here that is causing this issue:

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
        // your project's release build type.
        minifyEnabled true
        // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
        // Android Gradle plugin.
        shrinkResources true
        // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
        // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
        // R8 configuration files.
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }


}
```

Comment: You're most likely running a debug build from Android Studio. The app store one is a release build. Release builds can have different code and content, but since we're not seeing all the source code in your app, we cannot evaluate that.
Make a release build and evaluate on your dev machine if it works. Add logging if need be. Check any `src/release` folders (or similar) for code/content that deviates.

Comment: @KenVanHoeylandt I added some code, maybe there is something in my build.gradle causing this, can you please check it out?

Comment: ProGuard might be cutting out code from your application. I honestly don't know what the default rules do exactly, as I've only been using DexGuard (the paid version of ProGuard) with custom rules for the past years.

Comment: So my approach would be: disable ProGuard, make a release build, observe if the issue is gone. If the issue is gone, investigate which ProGuard rule is problematic. (e.g. add logging to your app to find out where it gets cut out)